# Por que TableView no acepta parametros?

Tags: javafx, netbeans-11

Estoy iniciando en ***Java Fx***. En estos momentos intento hacer funcionar una tabla y en todos los ejemplos que encontré, se utiliza ***TableView*** con parámetros. Mi ***Netbeans 11*** no me permite realizar esta acción.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi jdk es el 1.8.0_201

Que podria ser el problema...?

Comment: Por favor, trata de incluir siempre el código como texto, aunque también incluyas la imagen que muestra el error.

Comment: En este caso no hace falta debido a que el centro de la consulta es el mensaje que me lanza NetBeans.

Comment: Igualmente tuve que transcribir la línea problemática para darme a entender en la respuesta. Esta es una regla de la comunidad cuyo objetivo es este precisamente. Aunque tu consideres que el foco de atención es el mensaje del error quizá quien vaya a analizar el problema necesite probarlo y por tanto transcribirlo si lo que compartes es solo una imagen. Saludos.

Comment: Respeto tu opinión.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que tu clase que hereda de `Application` también se llama `TableView`. Por tal motivo la línea `TableView<Person> tableView = new TableView<>(data);` es interpretada por el copilador como que quieres crear una instancia de tu clase y no de la que tu quieres, que es la de JavaFX.

Para solucionar este problema cámbiale el nombre a tu clase o usa el ***fully-qualified class name*** de la clase de JavaFX que es `javafx.scene.control.TableView`. Quedaría así:

```
javafx.scene.control.TableView<Person> tableView = new javafx.scene.control.TableView<>(data);
```